# TailwindCSS - background image not loading on build

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, background-image

I'm doing a [Frontend Mentor challenge](https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/huddle-landing-page-with-a-single-introductory-section-B_2Wvxgi0/hub) and I've ran into a problem when publishing my project to Vercel.

The background image can't load. Everything works on my local machine, but when deployed, the only image that doesn't load is that background image.

1. I'm using the Vite buildtool, React and TailwindCSS.
2. The image path is **./public/images/bg-mobile.svg**
3. I imported the image in my **tailwind.config.cjs** and use it as a tailwin "bg-" class.

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, I'd be really happy to know.

```js
//tailwind.config.cjs
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "huddle-violet": "hsl(257, 40%, 49%)",
        "huddle-magenta": "hsl(300, 69%, 71%)",
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        "desktop": "url('./images/bg-desktop.svg')",
        "mobile": "url('./images/bg-mobile.svg')"
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require('prettier-plugin-tailwindcss')],
};
```

```html
//index.html
<body class="bg-huddle-violet bg-mobile bg-contain bg-no-repeat">
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
</body>
```

[Link to the hosted site](https://huddle-mini-project.vercel.app)

[Link to the Github repo](https://github.com/badmood111/huddle-landing-page-with-single-introductory-section-master/tree/45690cac7da263de18b980daaae6dd1072909af6)

Comment: Delete dot before '/images/bg-desktop.svg' and second path. it works for me.

Comment: @Lukas I feel like an idiot for writing such a long post when the problem is literally one character long..
Anyways, thank you Lukas, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
backgroundImage: {
  "desktop": "url('/images/bg-desktop.svg')",
  "mobile": "url('/images/bg-mobile.svg')"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The relative path being used is wrong.

`./` with this you mean one heirarchy up.

But according to your question `./public/images/bg-mobile.svg`

So try replacing `./` with `/` it should work.

Final code:

```
backgroundImage: {
  "desktop": "url('/images/bg-desktop.svg')",
  "mobile": "url('/images/bg-mobile.svg')"
},
```